# How to limit use of memory and processor in external process c#

Tags: c#

I'm using this right now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0
but I cannot limit the process memory and CPU usage

```cs
public static void Launch(string[] args)
        {
            // make sure installPath is in double perentheses
            string steamPath = config["steamPath"].ToString();
            string arg = "";
            foreach (string s in args){arg += $"{s} ";}
            Process ExternalProcess = new Process();
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.FileName = steamPath;
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            ExternalProcess.Start();
            ExternalProcess.WaitForExit(); 
            ExternalProcess.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I also found this but i can't get it to work: https://github.com/alonf/JobObjectWrapper

Comment: Look at [Process.PriorityClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass?view=net-6.0) property.

Comment: If setting constraints on memory usage are crucial, you might look into https://github.com/lowleveldesign/process-governor. It's a commandline tool, so it should be relatively easy to be executed by your C# program. It also allows limiting of CPU usage as well, so might perhaps be a one-stop solution you might be looking for...

Comment: so this will possibly work i want to have it inside the code and not an program where my program depends on

Comment: oh ok i will try to implement it first :)

Comment: does procgov exit the program or does it limit the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If setting constraints on memory usage are crucial, you might look into github.com/lowleveldesign/process-governor. It's a commandline tool, so it should be relatively easy to be executed by your C# program. It also allows limiting of CPU usage as well, so might perhaps be a one-stop solution you might be looking for... –
MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace